# Amazon Product Advertising API error: double callback bug when using await

Tags: node.js, amazon-product-api

I'm using to official Amazon NPM paapi5-nodejs-sdk

When I try to use await like this:

```
const testAsync = async function (){

  await api.searchItems(searchItemsRequest).then(
    function(data) {
      onSuccess(data);
    },
    function(error) {
      onError(error);
    }
  );

  console.log('this should log after await')
}

testAsync()
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: superagent request was sent twice, because both .end() and .then() were called. Never call .end() if you use promises
Warning: .end() was called twice. This is not supported in superagent
superagent: double callback bug
```

Actually, this happens **only** when I use the NPM package.
When I have altered the samples code Amazon provides [here](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/quick-start/using-sdk.html) with the same async-await it works OK.

Is there a bug in the NPM package? or am I missing anything?

Comment: I got the same issue. I didn't bother using their SDK though as I found an npm package wrapper that is easy to work with.
Please see link.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-paapi